# Confusion about one of the conditions for the Akra-Bazzi method solving recurrences

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

> In this [paper by Akra & Bazzi](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1018373005182), we consider linear divide-and-conquer recurrences of the form:
>   $$u_n = \begin{cases} u_0 & n = 0 \\ \sum_{i=1}^{k} a_{i} u_{\lfloor \frac{n}{b_{i}} \rfloor} + g(n) & n \ge 1 \end{cases}$$

One of the conditions is that:

> $g(x)$ is defined for real values $x$, and is ***bounded***, positive and nondecreasing function $\forall x \ge 0$.

My problem: what does "bounded" here mean? Does it mean $\exists M: \forall x: g(x) \le M$? If so, why does this method apply to, say, the example $u_n = 2 u_{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} + \Theta(n \log^2\log n)$ in Section 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original Akra-Bazzi paper has many inaccuracies. A corrected/extended version is Leighton's ["Notes on better master theorems for divide and conquer recurrences"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.39.1636) (1996). Sadly, there is no "formal" reference, and the conditions of the much sharper theorem there are hard to verify. A somewhat easier to apply version is the one in Lehman, Leighton and Meyer ["Mathematics for Computer Science"](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/spring18/mcs.pdf) (this is the latest lecture notes, there is a print version by Samurai Media from 2017 (ISBN 978-9888407064). The restriction cited there is that $\lvert g'(x) \rvert$ is bounded by a polynomial in $x$.